# Adding $ (dollar sign) to mutiple numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have some text that contain dollar amounts and other text. Some of the dollar amounts have $ other do not. Here are some examples:

- 1,000 up to 15,000
- $40
- 4000

I wish to add a $ at the beginning of each number if one doesn't already exist. My attempt:

```
function convertToMoney(text) {
  if (!text.match(/\$/)) {
    return text.replace(/\b([\d,]+)\b/g, function(d) { return('$'+d); });
  }
  return text;
}
```

If JS had [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) I would use

```
function convertToMoney(text) {
  return text.replace(/(?<!\$)\b(?:\d)/g, '$');
}
```

Can I simplify my long solution?

Can I get it to work with `1000 up to $4000`?

*UPDATE*

After applying @jfriend00 solution, my money filter looks like this:

```
function moneyFilter(text) 
  var ret = text;
  if (ret) {
    ret = ret
      .replace(/\.\d\d/g, '')                  // remove pennies
      .replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') // add comma
      .replace(/(\$?)(\d[\d,]+)/g, "$$$2");    // add dollar sign
  }
  return ret;
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just this:

```
function convertToMoney(text) {
    return text.replace(/(\$?)([\d,]+)/g, "$$$2");
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/y4k3k/

This finds any sequence of digits (optionally preceded by a $ sign) and replaces it with a dollar sign and the sequence of digits.

If you really wanted the `\b` you had in your regex, you could add this here too, but I didn't see that it was necessarily needed.

Comment: Thx. I was also wondering how to escape the $ sign in replace.

Answer (score 2):

How about first removing all $ from the text, then inserting one in front of every number?  Then you wouldn't have to worry about checking if it was already there.

Comment: Oddly enough, that is exactly what @jfriend00 is doing in a single pass.

Answer (score 0):

you can just correct the double dollar signs.

```
function convertToMoney(text) {
  if (!text.match(/\$/)) {
    newString = text.replace(/\b([\d,]+)\b/g, function(d) { return('$'+d); });
    return newString.replace(/\${2}/g, '$');
  }
  return text;
}
```